# Is self-penetration haram? Is it punishable?

Tags: sin

There is ruling for all sorts of sexualities but self-penetration is not discussed much. Would Islam classify it as homosexual act or what?

Comment: That doesn't seem humanly possible. Scholars don't talk about hypothetical situations.

Comment: There are many who can, including me.

Answer (score -1):

Sodomy is haram and masturbation is haram. An action in which you combine two haram things will also be haram.

Comment: Absolute correct. This obviously doesn't need any proof or evidence as this is a matter of pure common sense.